# Partition set of $n$ elements until each partition contains $1$ element. Must terminate after exactly $n-1$ iterations?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Suppose I have a set of $n$ elements and I want to partition the set (split into two) until each partition contains a single element.

How do I see that the terminating case must occur after exactly $n-1$ iterations ?

I've tried to draw tree-diagrams and other things, but I cannot come up with a rigorous proof ?

Answer (score 3):

Every time you split one set into two, the number of sets increases by one. At the beginning there is one set, at the end there is $n$. So there must be $n-1$ steps.

Answer (score 0):

**Adayah**’s answer is the most straightforward. You can also prove it by induction on $n$. Suppose that for each $k\le n$ you know that it takes exactly $k-1$ iterations. Now start with a set of $n+1$ elements. After the first iteration you will have two sets, say $K$ and $L$, of cardinalities $k$ and $\ell$, respectively. Clearly $k+\ell=n+1$ and $k,\ell\ge 1$, so $k,\ell\le n$. Thus, by the induction hypothesis you’ll need exactly $k-1$ iterations to reduce $K$ to singletons and $\ell-1$ to reduce $L$ to singletons, for a total of

$$1+(k-1)+(\ell-1)=k+\ell-1=n$$

iterations, as desired.